# How to call and read API REST with odoo 12 ( from my application to odoo)

Tags: rest, api, odoo-12

I created a REST API with my web application (PHP)  and I want to manage this data with Odoo.

So, I want to create my own module on Odoo to read this REST API from my web application with odoo 
(  i want to display the result of my API on odoo  not inverse ).

From My Application to odoo Not odoo to my application

Please guide me how to call and read the REST APIs with on Odoo.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Pls. post some code samples and what you are struggling with to give other users a chance to help you.

Comment: Did you  try to use requests?